# How do I keep the noise in my Cycles render (animation)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, denoise

Blender automatically reduces noise on Cycles renders now, but I don't want that. Googling this comes up only with ways to **reduce** noise, but I want to **keep** the noise you get in cycles.

Comment: It's the opposite to reduce noise, basically, turn in off denoise, lower render samples

Comment: @Emir Thanks, but how do I turn it off?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

You can turn off the denoising in the render settings. If you want even more noise, reduce the number of samples.

Comment: Thank you! it was right under my nose the whole time.